# VS2010 Reportviewer header hides the menu on my ASP.NET 4.0 site

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have a webforms asp.net 4.0 app, with a Webcontrols.Menu on the Site.Master.  This menu is configured as a DropDown menu.

On some of the pages I have a VS2010 ReportViewer on the page, and when it is rendered, the header row, of the report, will stay in front of the drop down menus.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Make the menus, render in front of the header?  I have looked at all the properties I could find for the header, or the rv webpart, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a CSS only problem. try playing with the stylesheet a bit or you can also change the `z-index` property of the menu bar.

Hope This helps.

Comment: That did the trick once I found the right place in the stylesheet. Thanks!  Good thing I'm not doing web dev for a living .... :D